# Rails poll users with different vote weight for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a poll app. I am modifying this https://www.sitepoint.com/polling-users-rails/ to my needs.

Users answer polls and results are shown.

```
polls

  t.string :question
  t.text :description
  t.references :division, foreign_key: true
  t.date :open_date
  t.date :close_date


vote_options

  t.string :title
  t.references :poll, foreign_key: true

votes

  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :vote_option, foreign_key: true

users
t.string :email
t.decimal :vote_weight
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :vote_options, through: :votes

def voted_for?(poll)
  vote_options.any? {|v| v.poll == poll }
end

end
```

vote_option.rb

```
class VoteOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
  validates :question, presence: true
  has_many :users, 
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

def get_vote_count
  VoteOption.joins(:votes).joins(:users).where(id: self.id).sum(:vote_weight)
end
end
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vote_option
  end
```

poll.helper

```
def visualize_votes_for(option)
    content_tag :div, class: 'progress' do
      content_tag :div, class: 'progress-bar',
                  style: "width: #{option.poll.normalized_votes_for(option)}%" do
        "#{option.votes.count}"
      end
```

visualize_votes_for shows total votes for each option. At the moment it considers 1 for each value and counts the total for each option.

I would like instead to be able to set a vote_weight for each user so that instead of 1 will be counted the value specified in vote_weight column in users table.

I have tried:

```
"#{sum(option.votes.user.vote_weight)}"
```

but it returns:

```
undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`option.votes` will return an active record collection of `votes`. Note that it will be a collection, not a single object. So, invoking method `user` on a collection will not work as a vote belongs to a user. So `user` method can be invoked only on an instance of `vote` object, not on collection. 
You can make a method `get_vote_count` in VoteOption Model

```
def get_vote_count
 Vote.joins(:vote_option).joins(:user).where("vote_options.id = #{self.id}").sum(:vote_weight)` # Adjust singularity/plurality of objects as per the requirement
end
```

And use this method in view dierctly on the option object like `option.get_vote_count`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Doing what you suggested returns Can't join 'VoteOption' to association named 'user'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Try `:users` instead of `user`.

Comment: ok changing to users returns Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.vote_option_id' in 'on clause': SELECT SUM(vote_weight) FROM `vote_options` INNER JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`vote_option_id` = `vote_options`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`vote_option_id` = `vote_options`.`id` WHERE `vote_options`.`id` = 6

Comment: I think the issue is on vote_option.rb where I set has_many :users If I remove it it returns Can't join 'VoteOption' to association named 'users'; perhaps you misspelled it?. If I change it to   has_many :users, through: :votes it returns Cannot have a has_many :through association 'VoteOption#users' which goes through 'VoteOption#votes' before the through association is defined.

Comment: Can you try `Vote.joins(:vote_option).joins(:user).where("vote_options.id = #{self.id}").sum(:vote_weight)` # Adjust singularity/plurality of objects as per the requirement

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!