# Rails poll app check if vote count for option has reached a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating an app to poll users. I started from [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/polling-users-rails/) and modified it. I also posted another question regarding it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251156/rails-poll-users-with-different-vote-weight-for-each-user).
Each user has a vote weight. So far users can vote and vote count (calculated based on vote weight of the user) for each option is displayed.

What I am trying to do now is to set a condition that checks if any of the options for that poll has reached 50%.

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vote_option
end
```

vote_option.rb

```
class VoteOption < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :poll
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_many :users, through: :votes
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

  def get_vote_count
    Vote.joins(:vote_option).joins(:user).where("vote_options.id = #{self.id}").sum(:vote_weight)
  end

end
```

poll.rb

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord

   validates :question, presence: true
   validates :division, presence: true
   validates :open_date, presence: true
   validates :close_date, presence: true
   before_save :set_position
   set_sortable :sort, without_updating_timestamps: true



   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
   has_many :votes, :through => :vote_options
   has_many :vote_options, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :division
   belongs_to :user
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :vote_options, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
   def normalized_votes_for(option)
     votes_summary == 0 ? 0 : (option.get_vote_count.to_f / votes_summary) * 100
   end

   def votes_summary
     vote_options.inject(0) {|summary, option| summary + option.get_vote_count}
   end

end
```

polls_helper.rb

```
module PollsHelper

  def visualize_votes_for(option)
    content_tag :div, class: 'progress' do
      content_tag :div, class: 'progress-bar',
                  style: "width: #{option.poll.normalized_votes_for(option)}%" do
        "#{option.get_vote_count}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

polls_controller show

```
def show
  @poll = Poll.includes(:vote_options).find_by_id(params[:id])
  @vote = Vote.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @users = @poll.users
  @comments = Comment.with_details.all

end
```

So on polls/show.html.erb I'd need something like:

```
<% if option.get_vote_count.any > 50 %>
do something 
<% end %>
```

How can I fix the code above to have it working? And what should I add on my polls_controller under show action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@poll = Poll.find(params[:id])` and then loop through `@poll.vote_options.each{|option| visualize_votes_for(option)}` - provided your routes are setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But adding the statement <% if option.get_vote_count.any > 50 %> inside the loop still returns undefined local variable or method `option' for #<#<Class.....

Comment: Best way to debug these types of issues is to print out all the variables you are expecting in your `polls/show.html.erb` so add simple statements like `<%= @poll %>` and `<%= @poll.options %>` - see what is set and what isn't.

Comment: `<%= @poll %>` is set as it returns `#<Poll:0x007fd01baadaa0>`. `<%= @poll.options %>` isn't set. `<%= @poll.vote_options %>` is set and returns`<VoteOption::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fd00a7de510>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution. Thanks to @Ash to point me on right direction:

```
  <% @poll.vote_options.each  do |option| %>
    <% if option.get_vote_count > 50 %>

    <h4> Condition met! </h4>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```